# Directive need to be new load on every click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a graph directive. Which show into a uib tabset. I want to new load again every time whene I click on any tab.

```
<uib-tabset active="activePill" vertical="true" type="pills">

    <uib-tab ng-repeat="physicalTest in patientinfo.physical_test_list"
                                  index="$index" heading="{{physicalTest.name}}" disable="physicalTest.disabled">

           <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-10">
                 <graph graph-data="physicalTest"></graph>
             </div>
           </div>

     </uib-tab>

</uib-tabset>
```

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: code code code code please

Comment: I add code. Please help me as soon as posible

Answer (score 0):

Wrap you directive inside parent HTML div or any element. The use ng-if to hide and show. When clicked in the tab, change the value of the variable to toggle show/hide

```
<div ng-if="showDirectiveA">
    <directive ...>
</div>
```

then in the tab

```
<div id="tab" ng-click="showDirectiveA = !showDirectiveA">
```

As per your code,

```
<uib-tabset active="activePill" vertical="true" type="pills">

<uib-tab ng-repeat="physicalTest in patientinfo.physical_test_list" ng-click="physicalTest.showGraph = !physicalTest.showGraph" index="$index" heading="{{physicalTest.name}}" disable="physicalTest.disabled">

       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-10" ng-if="physicalTest.showGraph">
             <graph graph-data="physicalTest"></graph>
         </div>
       </div>

 </uib-tab>
```

Comment: @RaisulIslam I have updated the answer. If you still face problems, please try to create a fiddle or plunkr with that

Comment: This two solutions are same. It's work but need double click.

Comment: @RaisulIslam can you please create a fiddle or plunkr for this